# Create stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will take an `ORDER BY <Country>` as a parameter to return the query order by that column which is country. What I have created so far is kind of rough, any help would be appreciate!

```
USE AdventureWorks2014
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspSort @CCountry nvarchar(15) 
AS 
    SELECT
        ContactName, CompanyName, Region, Country
    FROM 
        dbo.Customers
    ORDER BY 
        Country 
GO
```

Comment: Well...you aren't using your parameter in your code. But the bigger concern is that it isn't really clear what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to pass in the the name of the column to use as an order by? If so, you should probably change the datatype to sysname instead of nvarchar(15). And to actually make this work you will have to use dynamic sql which means you need to be careful about sql injection. bobby tables like to visit procedures like this.

Comment: @SeanLange that is correct, that exactly what I wish to do.

Answer (score 1):

A small dynamic SQL may help

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspSort (@CCountry nvarchar(15) = '1')
AS 

Declare @SQL varchar(max)
Set @SQL = 'SELECT ContactName, CompanyName, Region, Country FROM dbo.Customers ORDER BY '+@CCountry
Exec(@SQL)

GO
```

Comment: This work but there are a couple of concerns. First is the possibility of sql injection. You should wrap the parameter in QUOTENAME. Second concern is that you are using a deprecated feature when not passing in a value. When not passing in a parameter it will then order this by the ordinal position 1.

Comment: Great help oh wise oracles, I changed nvarchar (15) to sysname as advise and all is well in the land of stored procedure

Comment: @Suehil2k make sure you wrap that parameter in QUOTENAME or all is NOT well....yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by using the case statement, if you don't want to do dynamic sql.  All of the results of the case statement must be the same datatype (looks like they are all strings in your case, but be aware that if you mix int and varchar columns, you'll get an error).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspSort @OrderColumn nvarchar(15) 
AS 
    SELECT
        ContactName, CompanyName, Region, Country
    FROM 
        dbo.Customers
    ORDER BY 
        case @OrderColumn 
            when 'Country' then Country 
            when 'ContactName' then ContactName 
            when 'Region' then Region 
            when 'CompanyName' then CompanyName 
            else ''
        end
GO
```